# Rails Mailer call messes up controller routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to send out an email when a user submits a post. Here's what the relevant part my create action looks like in the post controller:

```
if @post.save
      UserMailer.alert_response(@post, @user).deliver
          respond_to do |format|
              format.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
            end

        else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
            end
          # redirect_to root_url
    end
```

and I've got a create.js.erb file that gets rendered whether the post saves or not. The alert_response method in my UserMailer controller looks like this:

```
def alert_response(post, user)
    @response_post = post
    @parent = post.parent
    @parent_user = @parent.user
    @user = user
    mail to: @parent_user, subject: "Someone Responded to Your Post"
  end
```

When I don't include UserMailer.alert_upvotes(@post, @user).deliver in the create action, everything works just fine. The create.js.erb file is rendered and that is all. When I do include it, the create.js.erb file is never rendered and for some reason the index action of my post controller gets fired and the index view gets rendered. Is there something wrong with my UserMailer call?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to create a new PostMailer controller with the appropriate action in it.